# Ubuntu's file-roller problem 5010. "Cannot open display"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip, unzip

I use "file-roller" to manage with archieves on my Ubuntu. But it fails on running without user interface(just teminal). The error is shown below.

```
** (file-roller:5453): CRITICAL **: Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

How can I prevent file-roller from using GUI or can you recommend me any other archieve manager I can use from terminal. It would be perfect, if this manager can handle as much formats as it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

`p7zip`, `unrar`, `gzip`, `tar` and `bzip2` are some popular archivers. For example, to compress a folder into gzipped tar, use the command:

`tar cvpzf FILENAME DIRECTORIES...`

Answer (score 1):

If you put this in your ~/.bashrc :

```
# Thanks to rezza at Arch Linux 
op () {
     if [ -f $1 ] ; then
        case $1 in
                *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf $1 ;;
                *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf $1 ;;
                *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1 ;;
                *.rar)       unrar x $1 ;;
                *.gz)        gunzip $1 ;;
                *.tar)       tar xvf $1 ;;
                *.tbz2)      tar xvjf $1 ;;
                *.tgz)       tar xvzf $1 ;;
                *.zip)       unzip $1 ;;
                *.Z)         uncompress $1 ;;
                *.7z)        7z x $1 ;;
                *)           xdg-open $1 ;;
        esac
     else
        echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
     fi
}
```

then you can open most archive files from the command-line with

```
op archivefile
```

If this does not work, then run

```
file archivefile
```

and post the output. We may be able to then tell you the right command for that kind of file.

PS. You may have to close the terminal and open a new one to make the change to ~/.bashrc effective.

Comment: Isn't there a standart util to do this?

Comment: @Denis, sure, there could be a standard util, though I don't know of one. What I suggest is not that hard, and is in line with the style of customization many people do with bash.

Comment: Ok as you see I am new to Ubuntu, bash, .. I am not against using hand written scripts, I just wonder how it will handle options?? For example destination folder. And what about packaging, I mean, building  archieves. I marked two answers as useful and great thx for your help! but I still wish anybody can provide a solution similar to file-roller, but with ability to be run from terminal. If  this question won't be answered for a long time I will mark this one as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Midnight Commander (mc)

Answer (score 0):

You must be running under root because root doesn't have a gnome configuration by default.  If you need to run it as root, file-roller can take other arguments available with other gnome commands.  See gtk-options.  To bypass this particular error, you can run file-roller like this:

```
file-roller --display=:0
```

It will still give you an error about the configuration but it's not critical and won't stop you from using file-roller as root.

OR

Stay logged in as the normal user and just sudo.

```
sudo file-roller filename
```